# Problem with html5 audio and javascript manipulation

Tags: html5-audio

I'm trying to manipulate an audio file (mp3), using `<audio>` and javascript but nothing happens when I click the link. The `alert()` is working but nothing happens with the audio i.e. no pause, no play, nothing..., whether in Safari or Firefox. Is the coding dodgy or what?

Check this out:

**jQuery/javascript:**

```
$(document).ready( function(){

  var audioElement = document.getElementById('audio_player');

  $('div.audioControls .play').live('click', function(){
    //alert('play');
    audioElement.play();
  });
  $('div.audioControls .pause').live('click', function(){
    //alert('pause');
    audioElement.pause();
  });
  $('div.audioControls .playatTime').live('click', function(){
    alert('play at time: 30 sec');
    audioElement.currentTime = 30;
    audioElement.play();
    return false;
  });

});
```

**HTML:**

```
<audio id="audio_player" controls="controls" src="aaliyah.mp3">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

<div class="audioControls">
<a href="#" class="play buttons" style="border:1px solid #ccc;">play</a>
<a href="#" class="pause buttons" style="border:1px solid #ccc;">pause</a>
<a href="#" class="playatTime buttons" style="border:1px solid #ccc;">play at 35   secondes</a>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now know why, it didn't work. To make use of the javascript API, the controls attributes needs to be removed from the html tag itself and it should work.

Thanks